# I can't see values of variable into the debugger

Tags: swift, xcode6

I am in full transition to Swift and I am having a problem with the debugger.

The problem is that I can't see the value of variable and class with a breakpoint.

When I type into the lldb console this command for example `po self`, the answer is:

> **error: :1:1: error: use of unresolved identifier 'self'**

My project compiles on debug mode.
I have Xcode 6.3.1 and i use swift 1.2.

Comment: Sometimes LLDB falls down on the job - especially with Swift. There's no magic solution. You might have to use logging from `println` or NSLog for some things instead.

Comment: @matt But me it isn't sometimes. On all my class, I can't see values of self. Do you think it's normal ?

Comment: Show more of your code and where the breakpoint is and I'll tell you what I see on my computer, if you like. But I'm afraid it is pretty normal. :(

Comment: @matt This is a screenshot of my Xcode. [Screenshot](http://www.casimages.com/i/150428012116143695.png.html)

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty inconsistent, but it does sometimes work, as this screen shot shows:

[image]

I don't know why it sometimes doesn't work, but I agree that sometimes it doesn't work! I often have to use `println(self)` in the code in order to know what's going on.